# Able to run script successfully in script editor but not from the sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I am attempting to get some information from Binance into Google Sheets using Google App Script. When I run the script from the script editor it correctly modifies the page based on the GET response. Here is the code for the function:

```
function getCoinUSDValueBinance(){

   var url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price'
   Logger.log('URL set');

   //Calling data from api
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'muteHttpExceptions': true});

   //Parse the data response to an object
   var dataResponse = JSON.parse(response);
   /* Work with Response here */

}
```

Unfortunately when I add the function to the api menu in sheets using the following code to add it to the menu:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.createMenu('API Menu')
    .addItem('Import GDAX Price Data', 'getAllCoinValues')
    .addItem('Binance', 'getCoinUSDValueBinance')
    .addToUi();
}
```

I end up getting a different response than when I am running the call in the Script editor. The response in the script editor is a 200 with the correct response body. The response in sheets is a 403 with a forbidden response body. How can I fix the incorrect response when the function is called on the sheet?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://ctrlq.org/code/20148-apps-script-execution-api-error) will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you can't add any function in a menu item that requires permissions in order to work. Which is the case with the URL fetch. You could work around this by using the button to open a dialogue or side bar that then has a button which calls the get function. This is a security feature of apps-script to prevent malicious code from executing on install or first open etc.